Преследование одного персонажа другим с помощью NavMesh (Unity 2D)
Подскажите пожалуйста, как корректно реализовать искусственное поведение персонажа №1, чтобы он следовал за персонажем №2 с тегом Player?
Я добавил навигационную сетку NavMesh на которой персонаж №1 передвигается.
Добавил компонент Nav Mesh Agent и следующий скрипт персонажу №1.
Но почему-то персонаж №1 исчезает, словно перемещается к персонажу №2 моментально. Как сделать, чтобы можно было увидеть перемещение персонажа №1, чтобы оно не происходило моментально?
Скрипт:


using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
 
public class Presledovanie : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string playerTag = "Player"; // Тег персонажа игрока
    private NavMeshAgent navMeshAgent;
    private Transform playerTransform;
 
    void Start()
    {
        navMeshAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
 
        GameObject player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(playerTag);
        if (player != null)
        {
            playerTransform = player.transform;
        }
    }
 
    void Update()
    {
        if (playerTransform != null)
        {
            navMeshAgent.SetDestination(playerTransform.position);
        }
    }
}



 Данные Nav Mesh Agent.

Возможный дубликат вопроса: Выполнение какого-либо действия по нажатию мыши на объект - Unity
